# connection to a databse from python script called from php

Tags: php, python, mysql, apache, permissions

I have a python script which executes the following line

> os.system('mysql -H -uusername -ppwd -hipaddr -e"some query" >filename.html')

when this python script is executed independently everything seems fine, a html file is generated with the query output.

But when i call the python script from php(using shell_exec()) ,there occurs a problem."filename.html" is created but the file is empty.When is searched regarding this i found this has to be done

> setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1.

As a result now i can connect to mysql using mysqldb module in python script called from php, which i am not in need of.
I want to execute query using execute command of mysql through os.system() which is still a problem when called from php.
Is there any suggestions so that i can get it right?

Edit :
here is my php script

```
<?php

$command = escapeshellcmd('python csv_generate.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
?>
```

here is my python script (csv_generate.py)

```
import sys
import os
print "hii"
query="show databases"
os.system('mysql -H -uaaa -pbbb -hhostip -P3306   -e"%s" >filename.html'%(query))
```

When called from php ,python script gets executed and it prints hii. The html file is also created but the file is empty .Even when i try to display the output in the browser 
i.e,

```
os.system('mysql -H -uaaa -pbbb -hhostip -P3306  -e"%s"'%(query))
```

it justs prints only "hii"

the error log contains

sh: /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql: Permission denied

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a sh file and put the commands to connect inside.

For Example, test.sh

```
python csv_generate.py
```

In PHP

```
exec("sh test.php");
```

So it does not fail execute the command

```
chmod 777 csv_generate.py
```

Comment: Make sure that /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql is also chmodded to 777